Bash script not renaming file
I'm trying to prepend photo DateTimeOriginal to file names, however the script can't rename?
linuxmint@linuxmint:~/Documents$ ./rename_prepend_date.sh /media/linuxmint/USB\ STICK/Old\ drive/My\ pictures/IMG_0569.JPG 
mv: cannot move '/media/linuxmint/USB STICK/Old drive/My pictures/IMG_0569.JPG' to '20110424_/media/linuxmint/USB STICK/Old drive/My pictures/IMG_0569.JPG': No such file or directory
Renamed '/media/linuxmint/USB STICK/Old drive/My pictures/IMG_0569.JPG' to '20110424_/media/linuxmint/USB STICK/Old drive/My pictures/IMG_0569.JPG'

Here's my bash script:
#!/bin/bash

# Check if exiftool is installed
if ! command -v exiftool &> /dev/null; then
    echo "exiftool is not installed. Please install it first."
    exit 1
fi

# Check if a file is provided as an argument
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <filename>"
    exit 1
fi

# Loop through each provided file
for file in "$@"; do
    # Get the date from the metadata (DateTimeOriginal)
    date=$(exiftool -d "%Y%m%d" -DateTimeOriginal "$file" | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')

    # Check if the date was successfully extracted
    if [ -z "$date" ]; then
        echo "Could not find a date for file $file. Skipping..."
        continue
    fi

    # Extract the file extension and base name
    extension="${file##*.}"
    base="${file%.*}"

    # Create the new filename by prepending the date
    new_file="${date}_${base}.${extension}"

    # Rename the file
    mv "$file" "$new_file"

    echo "Renamed '$file' to '$new_file'"
done


When you CD to /media/linuxmint/USB\ STICK/Old\ drive/My\ pictures/ then try renaming IMG_0569.JPG , you might find that it magically does work ! It is due prepending the date rightly , whereas , currently it is wrongly prepending to the whole path.

Before coming here for help, did you carefully read the error message? Look at it carefully, it says where it's trying to move to.

Your problem is that you're prepending the timestamp to the full path instead of just the basename. But you're making your life harder for nothing as exiftool supports renaming files based on tags found in the file by itself:
#! /bin/sh -
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  printf>&2 '%s\n' "Usage: $0 <filename> [<filename>...]"
  exit 1
fi
exec exiftool -d %Y%m%d -'FileName<${DateTimeOriginal}_${FileName}' -- "$@"

It's also safer as it will not rename if the tags can't be extracted or the destination file already exists.
By the way, you don't need awk if you write it:
exiftool -d %Y%m%d -p '$DateTimeOriginal' -- "$file"

Or:
exiftool -p '${DateTimeOriginal#;DateFmt("%Y%m%d")}' -- "$file"

Or:
exiftool -d %Y%m%d -s3 -DateTimeOriginal -- "$file"

(-s3 or -s -s -s, short short short to also skip printing the tag names).
Some other notes:

&> /dev/null is the only thing that is bash-specific in your script. If you replace it with > /dev/null 2>&1, your script becomes standard sh syntax, and you can change the shebang to #! /bin/sh - and remove the bash dependency. If I were to use a shell other than standard sh, I'd rather use zsh than bash here as it has builtin support to extract dirname (head) / basename (tail) /rootname / extension ($file:h / $file:t / $file:r / $file:e) and even a tool (zmv) to batch-rename files safely.

You should use -- (- also works for the sh, zsh or bash utilities in the shebang and is more idiomatic there) to separate options from non-options when you can't guarantee the non-options won't start with - (exiftool ... -- "$file", mv -- "$file" "$new_file"...)

echo can generally not be used for arbitrary data. Use printf instead.

errors should go to stderr. Some common function helpers:
println() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"
}
error() {
  println>&2 "$@"
}
die() {
  error "$@"
  exit 1
}

Then you can do:
date=$(exiftool...) && [ -z "$date" ] || die "Can't..."

Even information messages, anything that is not considered the output the script produces (and that one may want to make use of, likely none in your case) is usually preferably sent to stderr as it's intended for the interactive user, not for post-processing.

base="${file%.*}" removes the part after the last . in the full path. So in a dir.d/image, that gives you dir (and .d/image for  extension="${file##*.}"). Here you don't need to extract the extension as you're not doing anything useful with it, but in the general case, you want to make sure you do it only on the last component of the path (the base name).

"$@" is what for loops loop over by default, using for file do is more idiomatic (and more portable) than for file in "$@"; do.



Can you expand on your last point, please? I find for file  in "$@" better since it is clearer and makes what it loops over explicit. How is it less portable? The OP is using bash, are there any versions of bash that would work with for file do and choke on for file in "$@"?

@terdon, some versions of bash choke on "$@" when the nounset option is enabled and $# is 0, some other shells have the same issue or problem with $@ when IFS doesn't contain a space, or expand $@ to one empty argument if $# is 0 (hence the ${1+"$@"} still seen here and there) though that would be very old shells), I believe there's a Q&A covering it here. That's why for i do is often recommended even if it's unlikely any of the issues with "$@" will apply to the OP here.
